# Make ProFtpd ignore a blank command

Tags: linux, ftp, filter

Is there a way to make ProFtpd ignore a blank command?
Now it says "500 Invalid command: try being more creative"
This confuses a client ftp program.  The client (which I can't change) issues blank
commands occasionally - it shouldn't... but it does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for that purpose. Apart from editing the sourcecode and compiling ProFTPd yourself there is no way. I wouldn't recommend this option though, because you have to maintain these changes for security updates.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there was some creative way to do it.  eg use filters to turn the blank command into NOOP then ignore that command or something.